# Программа падает при объявлении массива

Tags: c++

Есть такие базовые типы:

```
//Класс двумерной точки
//Для задания начала и конца отрезков
class point{
private:
    double _x, _y;
public:
    point(){};
    point(double xn, double yn)
        : _x(xn), _y(yn) {}
    double x() {return _x;}
    double y() {return _y;}
    void setX(double value){_x = value;}
    void setY(double value){_y = value;}

    bool operator ==(const point p){
        if(this->_x == p._x && this->_y == p._y) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

//Упрощенный класс точки
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

// Глобальаня переменная, нужная для сортировки точек по отношению к первой точке
// Используется в функции compare для qsort()
// static для видимости только в пределах данного файла
static Point p0;

//Класс двумерного вектора
//Для определения вектора, соответствующего отрезку
class vector{
private:
    double _x, _y;
public:
    vector(double xn, double yn)
        : _x(xn), _y(yn) {}
    vector(point p1, point p2)
        : _x(p2.x() - p1.x()), _y(p2.y() - p1.y()){}
    double x() {return _x;}
    double y() {return _y;}
};

//Класс отрезка на плоскости
struct segment{
private:
    point _begin, _end;
    vector _v;  //Координаты вектора
public:
    segment()
        : _begin(0, 0), _end(0, 0), _v(0, 0){}
    segment(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
        : _begin(x1, y1), _end(x2, y2), _v(x2 - x1, y2 - y1){}
    point begin(){return _begin;}
    point end()  {return _end;}
    vector v()   {return _v;}
};
```

Вот в этом месте программа падает при запуске:

```
#define POINTS_AMOUNT 30000
#define SEGMENTS_AMOUNT 30000

int main(){
    //g::Point points[] = { { 0, 3 }, { 2, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 3, 3 } };
    g::Point points[POINTS_AMOUNT];
    g::Point rect[POINTS_AMOUNT];
    g::segment segments[SEGMENTS_AMOUNT];
    std::vector<g::Point> rect_vector, v;
    std::vector<g::segment> seg_vector;
```

Она стала падать после добавления строчки

```
g::segment segments[SEGMENTS_AMOUNT];
```

Из-за чего это может быть и как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаете на стеке несколько массивов по 30000 элементов, каждый из которых занимает несколько десятков, я думаю, байт. Стека не хватает и "ой все". Динамическое создание через new должно решить проблему.

Comment: А ещё можно размер стека увеличить

Comment: @Schullz а нужно ли?